Is being an agnostic self defeating?
The definition of agnostic as per Oxford is:

a person who believes that nothing is known or can be known of the existence or nature of God or of anything beyond material phenomena; a person who claims neither faith nor disbelief in God.

My question is specifically about the “nothing can be known” part about the definition rather than the “nothing is known” part. If a person believes that nothing can be known about God, isn’t this itself a knowledge claim about God, thus contradicting his own belief?

More the other way round: if something isn't known then it implies that something is knowable.

The self-contradiction of such an agnostic subtly depends on such belief or knowledge is necessary or not. In the weaker version of contingently unknown which seems the case from your quotation here, there's no logical paradox here. The agnostic happens to be unable to know any such proposition about the existence or nature of God in this actual world since such knowledge isn't necessary across all PWs. But if the agnostic claims the stronger version to assert impossibility, then it's self-defeating since if such knowledge falls on the actual world the agnostic will know sooner or later...

What's the point of asking this? Sure, when interpreted literally, there's a contradiction. But we all know what they are trying to say, and you can trivially reword this to remove the contradiction.

@HolyBlackCat you can trivially reword anything to remove a contradiction

You are (intentionally or unintentionally) missing my point. What I'm saying is that the concept of agnosticism by itself isn't contradictory, they've just conveyed it in a flawed way. They (and most agnostics) intuitively don't include "the fact that nothing is known or can be known of the existence or nature of God" into the "information about the nature of God (that can't be known)" category. If you add this clarification to the definition, there's no contradiction.

@HolyBlackCat many agnostics believe that nothing can be known about God. Are you saying that Oxford’s definition is more flawed than yours? Why is yours correct and not Oxford’s?

Because mine isn't self-contradictory. And again, I don't believe that their intent was to give a self-contradictory definition, otherwise they would've mentioned the contradiction right next to it. Either this is a minor wording defect, or they're using a slightly different definition of "nature [of God]" that excludes the "nothing can be known about ..." concept.

The definition you quote is one of many. The one you quote does not operationalize the concept very well.
An alternative is presented by Paul Draper, "Atheism  and Agnosticism", Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

Nowadays, the term “agnostic” is often used (when the issue is God’s existence) to refer to those who follow the recommendation expressed in the conclusion of Huxley’s argument: an agnostic is a person who has entertained the proposition that there is a God but believes neither that it is true nor that it is false.

A person who is an agnostic under that definition is not contradiciting any of their beliefs. They just have failed to come around to an affirmative position about the proposition "there is a God," one way or the other.
However, focusing on the definition you have quoted, your question just becomes a specialization of Is Philosopical Skepticism self-defeating?

That objection isn't even semantic; it's merely syntactic.
The agnostic is making a statement about something that doesn't exist. All unicorns have horns, therefore unicorns exist.
No, they don't.
You can gussy that up and say it in a fancy, complicated way. But you can dump all the complexity if you can see through it to the simplicity.
